# Laravel unable to create Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm unable to create an Eloquent model on one column. Edit an existing entry is possible.
Nothing will be logged to the laravel.log or php.log.
as 30 other models are working fine I've no idea what's the issue here.

I tried already to remove

```
use Userstamps, SoftDeletes, Billable;
```

thanks

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\Userstamps;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class Company extends Model
{
    use Userstamps, SoftDeletes, Billable;
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $fillable = array(
        'name', 'stripe_id', 'card_brand', 'card_last_four', 'trial_ends_at', 'email', 'street', 'city', 'country', 'state', 'zip', 'fn', 'ln', 'phone'
    );
}
```

Controller

```
$company = \App\Company::created(array(
            'name' => 'test',
            'street' => '12',
            'city' => '12',
            'country' => '12',
            'state' => '12',
            'zip' => '12',
            'fn' => '12',
            'ln' => '12',
            'phone' => '12',
            'fax' => '12',
        ));
```

Migration

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('deleted_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('zip');
            $table->string('fn')->nullable();
            $table->string('ln')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('fax')->nullable();
        });
```

Comment: \App\Company::created or **\App\Company::create**

Comment: `\App\Company::created` or `\App\Company::create`?

Comment: Wow, word for word haha.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on logging for development.  You should have display errors on and laravel app_debug set to true in .env.

Comment: shame on me...
I have read the text 10 times
thx guy's and sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$fillable` property is set wrong. You're missing `fax` for example. Make sure that every column that you want to make available for mass assignment is set within the `$fillable` array.